# Using SSH for both SFTP AND Port Forwarding in a chroot'ed environment

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, portforwarding, chroot

My goal is to have these things working:

- User can connect to Server via sftp. He can only read contents from his home directory (hence, he can use *sftp user@host*)
- User can connect to Server and open a remote port for port forwarding (hence, he can use *ssh -R remote_port:localhost:port user@host*)
- User can **not** do anything but those two things. He should not have normal shell access and should not be able to run commands.

I can get either case to work, but not both at the same time.

My /etc/sshd_config is:

```
Match Group restricted
    ChrootDirectory /home/restricted/users
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Obviously this is the working case for sftp. With this configuration, it is impossible to open a remote port for port forwarding.

The only way for me currently to allow tcp forwarding is disabling the *ForceCommand* and the *ChrootDirectory* directives.

Also, I have to change the shell to /bin/bash to allow port forwarding.

My dream situation would be:

- /bin/false (or equivalent) as shell
- chrooted to home directory
- sftp works
- port forwarding works
- nothing else works

Is that even possible? And if so, what do I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not server configuration.

Comment: You could implement this in a custom SSH server written with Paramiko or a similar library. Problems you hit during this development effort might be on-topic here. :)

Comment: (Specifically, the Python version of Paramiko; the Java port doesn't have SFTP server support).

Comment: ...that said, from the end-user configuration perspective, have you _tried_ using `ssh -N` on the client side, to avoid requesting a shell (which obviously isn't allowed in this configuration)? Mind you, I haven't looked at the source to see if this is possible, but it's more likely to work than not. :)

Comment: Wow, I spent hours trying to find the right server configuration when all I had to do was adding a *-N*. Feel kind of embarrassed ;) Thanks Charles Duffy for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. This was a good question -- I'd like to see it migrated to ServerFault or Unix SE or otherwise somewhere it's on-topic; might file a flag asking moderators to consider that, if it doesn't get closed in a way that automates making it a migration candidate.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to *Charles Duffy*, I know what I did wrong. The above configuration *does* indeed work, however, I had to add a "-N" to my ssh client request:

```
ssh -N -R remote_port:localhost:port user@host
```

this does also work with shell set to /bin/false

Sorry about choosing the wrong section, I'm going to try unix.stackexchange next time.

Thanks again!